# Torquebox Infinispan Cache - Too many open files

Tags: ruby, caching, jboss7.x, infinispan, torquebox

I looked around and apparently Infinispan has a limit on the amount of keys you can store when persisting data to the FileStore.  I get the "too many open files" exception.

I love the idea of torquebox and was anxious to slim down the stack and just use Infinispan instead of Redis.  I have an app that needs to cache allot of data. The queries are computationally expensive and need to be re-computed daily (phone and other productivity metrics by agent in a call center).

I don't run a cluster though I understand the cache would persist if I had at least one app running.  I would rather like to persist the cache.  Has anybody run into this issue and have a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Infinispan's FileCacheStore used to have an issue with opening too many files. The new SingleFileStore in 5.3.x solves that problem, but it looks like Torquebox still uses Infinispan 5.1.x (https://github.com/torquebox/torquebox/blob/master/pom.xml#L277).

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I am using Torquebox' JBoss instillation and not the wrapper. Guess I could just install JBoss complete which should have the current release of Infinispan and use the Torquebox wrapper instead. You know its odd to me though that it generates so many files. Guess I'm just used to Redis. Guess the limitation is lifted bu it still generates that many files? I would like to keep a heavy amount of keys cached. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hmm, if you have lots of entries you might have some problems even with the new SingleFileStore, because it stores everything in one file, but it keeps all the keys in memory. Our recommended solution for when you can't keep all the keys in memory is to use the LevelDB store (also only available in 5.3.x).

Comment: Good to know. I'm a Ruby man and as such slave to the torquebox api. I'll have a house cleaning job to remove keys I don't need or simply invalidate the cache on a timer. Othewrise I'm going to have to refresh myself with some j2ee and get my hands dirty :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using `infinispan` cache in a live application.

Basically we are storing database queries and its result in cache for tables which are not up-datable and smaller in data size.

There are two approaches to design it:

- Use queries as key and its data as value

  It leads to too many entries in cache when so many different queries are placed into it.
- Use `xyz` as key and `Map` as value (`Map` contains the queries as key and its data as value)

  It leads to single entry in cache whenever data is needed from this cache (I call it query cache) retrieve `Map` first by using key `xyz` then find the query in `Map` itself.

We are using second approach.

Comment: Interesting. I just cache with a scheduled morning job that feeds in key/values with namespaced keys with values as json serialized strings. e.g. key :"phones:123456:mar-w1-2014" value [{employeeid:123456,callshandled:10,handletime:3600,week:'MAR-W1-2014'}..]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What is the issue?